# Add PDF font to JasperReport export

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, itext

I am using iReport to create a series of reports. In iReport my default font is set to "SansSerif"; on my machine (Ubuntu Linux) this is actually DejaVu Sans. Ultimately the reports need to be rendered as PDF files. When a PDF is generated the text font is actually Helvetica and is causing formatting issues. Ideally the font in iReport would be the same as the PDF font. That is where my issue resides.

I have tried changing the `net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name` setting to 'DejaVu Sans' but that throws an error about the font not being found. From what I understand it is actually iText creating the PDF. Is that correct? In the iText jar Helvetica is embedded in the jar. Does the same thing need to be done to the other fonts? How does one go about that?

I have researched this and tried all kinds of things. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried other fonts?

Comment: Yes. All of the fonts in the iText package work. Everything else fails.

Answer (score 0):

1. To install missing fonts in iReport, Access the following sub-items from the menu bar 
   `Tools > Options >Fonts > Install Font`
2. Add fonts files e.g garamond.otf,
3. Add font family details
4. Select locale of your country
5. Manage font mapping to avoid the missing font property in OS
6. After adding all required fonts click on Export as extension to save the jar extension
7. Add this *Jasperreport-font.x.x.x.jar* on your project library or classpath